# How to copy the sequence numbers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

For a postgres based database I need to mirror the table definitions and sequence numbers from one schema to another. For the purpose of copying the schema definitions, I've been able to use pg_dump with schema definition only, however documentation seems to indicate that sequence numbers are only exported when data export is selected.

Is there an easy to export the corresponding sequence numbers in the schema exportation or an easy way to transfer these values or is the only alternative to interface with the database from a scripting language?

Comment: You have to keep in mind that pg_dump & pg_restore are primarily used for backup and restore-style processes. Without data it usually makes more sense to start all sequences from 1. Why would you start the sequences from their previous values from the mirrored db?

Comment: If you don't copy the data, then why do you need the sequence values to in sync?

Comment: I am performing an partial conditioned data-migration so I need the sequence numbers to remain intact to keep them from generating sequences that previously have already been assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the dump the pg_dump first writes the creation of the sequence and the corrects that start value with

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('tuutti_id_seq', 4, true);
```

So if you do a schema-only dump you can construct the statement from information schema, for example with SQL query:

```
SELECT 'SELECT pg_catalog.setval(''' || sequence_name || ''', ' || start_value || ', true);'
  FROM information_schema.sequences;
```